# Link google's +1 to my website's +1 page, or to my website itself

Tags: google, google-plus, google-plus-one, google-plus-pages

My current Google plus one link is tied to my business' Google+ page and it was nice to see that when I moved my website to another domain the new domain has all the +1s (as its Google+ page hasn't changed)

But I actually want Google to pay more attention to my website itself and not to my website's Google+ page.

what link is better to be used for plusone href considering that my purpose is to lead people to my website and not to my Google+ page?

Answer (score 1):

Your +1 links should either refer to the website's top-level domain or the specific page on which it's placed. You should then use the rel="publisher" element or a verification via Webmaster Tools in order to tie-in the relationship between your site and your Google+ page.

Answer (score 1):

Using g:follow gives more with the "rel" then client:plusone.js, and if 
the users are allowed to sign in with button class="g-signin" you can go in more details defining onSignInCallback. https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/